# Canvas: Drag and Drop Images

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

so I am relatively new to javascript. As a school project, we have to code a game with HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

So I want to make a cheap recreate of the game Sort or 'Splode' from New Super Mario Bros Ds.

I already programmed the random spawning of the bombs and animated the movement of the bombs. If they are too long in the middle sector (where they spawn) the explode.

But I didn't program the explosion yet. I want to program the drag and drop first. I just want to drag and drop a bomb. As simple as that, the rest I could do myself I guess.

I searched for a tutorial and found this webpage: https://html5.litten.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-on-an-html5-canvas/

I sort of recreated this in my game, but it is not working...

Sorry for my bad code. Could someone please explain to me how to do that?

Best,
Sebastian

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33maR.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BOMB-Sorter</title>

<style>
canvas {
    background-color:#fff;
    border:7px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline;
    background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

body{
    display: flex;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}


</style>
<script>

class GraphObj {

  constructor(x, y, w, h, c, x_vel, y_vel, t, d) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.c = c;
    this.x_vel = x_vel;
    this.y_vel = y_vel;
    this.t = t;
    this.d = d;
  }

  info() {
    return "\ngraphical object: x="+this.x + ", y="+this.y+", w="+this.w+", h="+this.h+", h="+this.c;
  }
}


// Declaration of Lists
var bList = null; // List of Bombs
var xlist = null;
var ylist = null;

var ref_time=0; // Reference Time
var lives = 10;
var score = 0;

var dragok = false;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");



function drawGrid(ele,ctx){ // declaration of a new function
    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff9999";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,ele.width/3,ele.height)

    ctx.fillStyle = "#60615a";
    ctx.fillRect(2* (ele.width/3),0,ele.width/3,ele.height)

    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.setLineDash([25, 15]);
    ctx.moveTo(ele.width/3 +1,0);
    ctx.lineTo(ele.width/3 +1, ele.height);

    ctx.moveTo(2*(ele.width/3 -1),0);
    ctx.lineTo(2*(ele.width/3 - 1), ele.height);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#f5f242";
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawAll()
{
    var ele = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = ele.getContext("2d");
    
    ele.width = ele.width; // clear everything!

    drawGrid(ele,ctx); // call the function ...
    
    var bombb = document.getElementById("bombb");
    var bombr = document.getElementById("bombr");
    var bombr_step = document.getElementById("bombr_step");
    var bombb_step = document.getElementById("bombb_step");
    var bombw = document.getElementById("bombw");

    // draw bombs
    for (var i=0; i<bList.length; i++)
    {
        var o = bList[i];
        if(o.c == 0 && o.t != 8 && o.t != 10 ){
            ctx.drawImage(bombr, o.x,o.y,o.w,o.h);
            draggable: true;
        }

        if(o.c == 1 && o.t != 8 && o.t != 10 ){
            ctx.drawImage(bombb, o.x,o.y,o.w,o.h);
            draggable: true;
        }

        if(o.c == 2 && o.t != 8 && o.t != 10 ){
            ctx.drawImage(bombr_step, o.x,o.y,o.w,o.h);
            draggable: true;
        }

        if(o.c == 3 && o.t != 8 && o.t != 10 ){
            ctx.drawImage(bombb_step, o.x,o.y,o.w,o.h);
            draggable: true;
        }

        if(o.t == 10 || o.t == 8){
            ctx.drawImage(bombw, o.x,o.y,o.w,o.h);
            draggable: true;
        }


    }
    
    // draw lives
    ctx.font = "normal small-caps 70px Minecraft";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText(+lives, ele.width - 105, 70);

    // draw score
    ctx.font = "normal small-caps 70px Minecraft";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(+score, 20, 70);

}

function positionCheck(i, ele){
        if(bList[i].x < ele.width/3){
            bList[i].x_vel = bList[i].x_vel * (-1);
        }
        else if(bList[i].x > 2*(ele.width/3) -64){
            bList[i].x_vel = bList[i].x_vel * (-1);
        }
        else if(bList[i].y < 0){
            bList[i].y_vel = bList[i].y_vel * (-1);
        }
        else if(bList[i].y > ele.height -64){
            bList[i].y_vel = bList[i].y_vel * (-1);
        }
}

function animateStep(){
    
    for(var i = 0;i < bList.length; i++){

            if(bList[i].c == 0){
                bList[i].c = 2;
                bList[i].t++;
            }
            else if(bList[i].c == 1){
                bList[i].c = 3;
                bList[i].t++;
            }
            else if(bList[i].c == 2){
                bList[i].c = 0;
            }
            else if(bList[i].c == 3){
                bList[i].c = 1;
            }   

            else if(bList[i].t == 8){
            bList[i].c = 4;
            }

            else if(bList[i].t == 10){
            bList[i].c = 4;
            }

    }
}

function functimer(){

    var ele = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    
    // create new bomb every s
    if (Date.now() - ref_time >= 1000)
    {
        // random number between 0 and ele.width
        var pos_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (ele.width/3 - 64)) + (ele.width/3 +1); 

        //random height
        var pos_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (ele.height - 70) -1);

        //random color
        var color = Math.round(Math.random());
        
        //random x velocity
        var x_vel = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1);

        //random y velocity
        var y_vel = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1);

        var t = 0;

        var o = new GraphObj(pos_x,pos_y,64,64, color, x_vel, y_vel, t); // create new bomb
        bList.push(o);

        animateStep();

        ref_time = Date.now();
    }
    
    var xlist = null;
    xlist = new Array();

    var ylist = null;
    ylist = new Array();


    // move bombs
    for (var i=0; i<bList.length; i++)
    {
        bList[i].y += bList[i].y_vel;
        bList[i].x += bList[i].x_vel;
        positionCheck(i, ele);
    }

    drawAll();
    requestAnimationFrame(functimer); // draw everything BEFORE screen update
    
}

function myMove(i,e){
    if(dragok == true){
        bList[i].x = e.pageX - c.offsetLeft;
        bList[i].y = e.pageY - c.offsetTop;
    }
}


function myDown(e){
    for(var i = 0; i < bList.lenght; i++){
        if(e.pageX < bList[i].x + 64 + c.offsetLeft && e.pageX > bList[i].x + c.offsetLeft && e.pageY < bList[i].y + 64 + c.offsetTop && e.pageY > bList[i].y + c.offsetTop){

            bList[i].x = e.pageX - c.offsetLeft;
            bList[i].y = e.pageY - c.offsetTop;
            bList[i].x_vele = 0;
            bList[i].y_vel = 0;
            dragok = true;
            c.onmousemove = myMove(i,e);
        }
    }
}

function myUp(){
    dragok = false; 
}

function start() {
    // create lists
    
    bList = new Array();
    
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    c.setAttribute('tabindex','0');
    c.focus();
    c.onmousedown = myDown;
    c.onmouseup = myUp;

    var xlist = null;
    xlist = new Array();

    var ylist = null;
    ylist = new Array();

    drawAll();
    requestAnimationFrame(functimer); // draw everything BEFORE screen update

    
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="start()">

<img id="bombb" src="img/bombb.png" alt="x" style="display: none;">
<img id="bombr" src="img/bombr.png" alt="y" style="display: none;">
<img id="bombr_step" src="img/bombr_step1.png" alt="y" style="display: none;">
<img id="bombb_step" src="img/bombb_step.png" alt="y" style="display: none;">
<img id="bombw" src="img/bombw.png" alt="y" style="display: none;">

<div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, your bombs are not rectangles, and there are lots of them and they overlap. Do you know how you are going to tell whether one bomb is (partly) on top of another? Is there a sort of stacking order?

Comment: @AHaworth I didnt know, that this is a problem. I thought because also one is drawn over the other, that it selects automatically the bomb that is drawn over the other.

Comment: Hi, what I think the code does is to see whether the mouse is within the rectangle of a bomb and if so selects it, so a bomb partly behind won’t get chosen if it is clicked on part that is within that rectangle. This may not matter to your game, I don’t know what the rules are, but I’ll hope to have a closer look in a few hours so I understand better what is required.

Comment: Another thing to look at carefully is where things are declared - what is their scope. For example you are declaring a variable 'c' in the start function, but it won't be the same c as is used in some of the functions as the scope is different.

Comment: If  you remove the 'var' from before the var c = .... in function start() you will be using the global c throughout and this at least means we begin to see some action when we try to drag a bomb. Can you describe what you want to happen when a bomb is dragged? Where is it supposed to go?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a total answer because I do not know exactly what is required when dragging a bomb, but here are a few places to make changes to help further debugging:

the canvas element 'c' is declared in two places so when it comes to be used on mousedown etc it is undefined, the one with more local scope having been set up in the start function. I suggest removing the 'var' before the use of c in the start function so you pick up the one that has global scope.

In general, go through the code seeing where things are defined and if that is in the best position - look at the scope of all variables. The code in this respect is almost OK, for example you understand you cant draw an img on a canvas until it is downloaded, but a few things could do with tidying up.

There is a misspelling of 'length' (lenght) which means a function won't work.

In general use your browser's dev tools console to ensure you do not have anything undeclared or looking like null etc. Such Javascript errors will show there. Also use console.log at strategic points to make sure you understand the flow of the logic. Starting with console.log('at function xxx') at the beginning of the main functions might be useful. You can then see the order in which mousedown/up might happen on a bomb for example.

If you could describe further what should happen when a bomb is dragged that would be useful. Just for completeness here I reiterate what I said in a comment that the bombs are going to be treated like rectangles - so obscuring bombs behind them from the point of view of dragging - that may or may not matter to your application. There is a way round it if it is important, but it's probably better to get the basics sorted out first.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answers. First of All, sorry for my late reply. I was fixing a other problem. Basically i program the game 'Sort a Splode' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6c9iqOvDWU just without the fancy animations and co.

Comment: So i have 3 sectores drawn in my canvas. And the goal is to drag the red bombs to the red site and the black bombs to the black site before they explode. When they stay in the middle part (where they spawn, and move around) they explode after a amount of time- I created the explosion animation, now so i changed a bit.